# What's going on with this question?

Tags: discussion

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/442521/revisions ????

The author is CONSTANTLY vandalizing his own post so a to make it unintelligible, with other users trying to save it.  It's been locked, unlocked, deleted, and undeleted by divine intervention.

I'm downvoting, because I'm petty and pissed, especially about the useless intervention from on high, and will vote to delete if the option ever appears to me.  If it gets edited back to remove the figure, I'm flagging it as vandalism, and I suggests everybody do the same.

If the author has a reason to delete the figures, perhaps he should request deletion of the question, or reword it to make it understandable.

Comment: @DaveTweed The author has a post up in "Ask a Moderator" requesting assistance

Comment: It's out of the moderators' hands and SE staff is dealing with it.

Comment: Looks like the Tweet had interesting effects!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OP's requests in comments and chat, they wanted to remove the original images from the question. They had stated they would be in legal trouble if they could not.

They clearly wanted to delete the question, but you can't delete your own question when it has upvoted answers. Unsure how to contact a mod to remove the question, they resorted to vandalizing the post (repeatedly). Chalk it up to a mixture of unfamiliarity with the site and posting something they shouldn't have (or believed they shouldn't have).

It sounds like they spoke to the site mods and/or SE staff to resolve. They were given one last attempt to remove the offending information without rendering the question unanswerable, and did so [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/442521/17). The whole debacle should be over, now.